# Shoppingcart open in multiple tabs

Tags: c#, tabs, shopping-cart, commerce

I am looking for tips on solving the following problem in a web store:

I have an online store where customers can buy bus tickets. Sometimes the customers have the website open in several tabs and while planning a trip they search for tickets and prices in all tabs, sometimes adding different tickets to the shopping cart in different tabs. When they are ready to finish the order in one tab, the selections made in other tabs will also be included in the final order.

Edit:
The problem is that the shoppingcart is being populated from all tabs and if the user checks out from for example the first tab he opened then all tickets added in all tabs are included in the order even if the shoppingcart in the tab is just showing two tickets (if the user refreshes the shoppingcart it updates and there is no problem). If the user does not pay attention to the sub total when paying then he or she might be buying more tickets than intended...

The solution that I am working on is an **"old"** one (`.Net/C#`) so I am unfortunately building a solution from scratch. When the users add a ticket to the shopping cart a cartId (cookie) is created and this is being used across all browser windows/tabs.

I guess there are several ways to solve this problem, and currently I am very unsure how to do it in an effective and smart way.

Comment: I'm not clear what the problem is you are trying to solve. Does your shopping cart not currently work the way you want it to ? Multi-window single-cart is normal and cookies can be done to create this, or better still a back-end session based cart. Can you rephrase your question to make it more clear exactly what technical problem you are facing ?

Comment: I edited the question to try to explain the problem better. The problem is more theoretical than technical...I guess I can add another step in the web shop where the user has to confirm the order, but I am not sure this is the best solution...

Comment: If you are working in the European Union you absolutely must have a seperate page where the user sees and confirms their entire order - its part of the legislation on distance selling.

Comment: Not working in the EU, but I want this feature anyway ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an [ASP.NET session](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) for this. Each time user adds or delete an item on shopping cart, update your session. When user checks out, retrieve the data from the Session, which will always have all the items added in different tabs.